# Add new contacts to specific gmail account

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest, gmail, google-contacts-api, gmail-api

I'm looking into adding a list of contacts to my gmail account as I will need to export contacts from software and then automatically upload these contacts to my gmail account. I've been looking into this and there is a lot of information about OAuth but this all seems to find the users google account and allow me to make changes to that, which is far more complex than I need.

I was thinking it should be something like this:

```
<HTTPRequest url="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full" operation="POST" _Authorization="CLIENT_ID">
         <HTTPRequestData>
            SEND DATA HERE

          </HTTPReuestData>
 </HTTPRequest>
```

but I have no idea how to specify that I want to update 1 specific gmail account. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no other way to access Google API or protected data stored on Google services without using OAUTH 2.0 protocol.
Hope this helps you!!